# AutoCompleteTextview singleLine setText() with text longer than view size will cause broken words

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have the following `AutoCompleteTextView` :

```xml
  <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/contact_list_auto_complete_text_view"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:hint=" Enter number"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
  </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

The input to this `AutoCompleteTextView` is done via a "Dialer" Layout I've created , thus this `AutoCompleteTextView` is `android:enabled="false"` and in order to add the user input on my `AutoCompleteTextView` I use the following code :

```
   String mText =_searchAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString()+_dialer_digits[position]; //the digit the user clicked upon 
  _searchAutoCompleteTextView.setText(mText);
  _searchAutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion();
  if(_searchAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().length()>2 &&  _searchAutoCompleteTextView.getAdapter().getCount()> 0)
  {
    _searchAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
  }
```

Every thing is working fine except a weird issue : 
Since the input is not done by the device's keyboard and only by my dialer with `setText()` , if the user clicks alot of digits whihc are longer than the `AutoCompleteTextView`'s size last digit is broken and while continuing to input more digits the `AutoCompleteTextView` does not scroll left. The weird thing about it is that I've tried to enable it and put some long input from the device's keyboard it works perfectly , long text is not broken and scrolling is happening. Since I cannot use the device's keyboard it must be done via my layout and `setText()`

Many thanks ahead

EDIT:

here is a screen shot : 
[image: My dialer layout with broken digit at the end]

Comment: What do you expect? Do you want to scroll it by finger or you want to show the end of string (and corrupt on start)

Comment: @Demand I want to show the end of the String (and corrupt on start) I've tried `android:ellipsize` it's not working. I feel like the `setText()` is not doing something whereas the input from keyboard does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use append instead of setText to move the cursor to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but have you tried to put your AutoCompleteTextView in a HorizontalScrollView?

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_list_auto_complete_text_view"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:hint=" Enter number"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Can you provide a screen shot so I can better understand the issue you are having?

Comment: Hey , I added a screen shot. I want the text inside to scroll as should the `AutoCompleteTextView` itself

Comment: @EviatarS Thanks for the screen shot.  After calling setText this will move the cursor to the end and may fix your issue: _searchAutoCompleteTextView.setSelection(_searchAutoCompleteTextView.getText().length());

Comment: @EviatarS Actually you can use append instead of setText and the cursor will automatically go to the end.

Comment: append worked. please write an answer to use append on `AutoCompleteTextView` and I will mark it , cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Gravity of AutocompleteTextVIew to right:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_list_auto_complete_text_view"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:hint=" Enter number"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```